# How to create db link for user in database?

Tags: database, oracle, dblink

I have 2 users. 1 is cashflowuser and second one is salinvoiceuser in `oracle` server.

I want to create db link in cashflowuser for salinvoiceuser.

For that I have created using this - connected to cashflowuser and execute below query:

```
create database link ORASALINV_80 connect to SALINVOICEUSER 
  identified by cashflowuser using 'oracle';
```

identified by password we need to give. But what user password we need to give? cashflowuser password or salinvoiceuser password?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please use appropriate tags and format your code for better readability. Now coming to your question, since you said you have two users i.e. two schemas. So **are these two schemas in same database or you want to connect remotely to the schema on other database?** Else, you just need to grant required privileges to the other user to access the objects of another user.

And `identified by` clause is used to provide **password** for the database link.

Comment: DB links are for connecting two **physical** databases. It seems like you just have two schemas in the **same** database? Is that corrected? Are you just looking for GRANT command?

Comment: @Radagast81 paswrord but what user password? means the password i want to connect to or password i want to connect from ?

Comment: @Radagast81 That's not correct. **Identified by** clause is used to provide **password** and USING to provide **connect string**. See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205

Comment: @Radagast81 as you said Identified by clause is used to proived password. Now my doubt is which user pasword i need to provide? means the user i want to connect or the user i want to connect from?

Comment: You just have to say how to connect via db_link, so it's allways the password and schema you want to connect to.

Comment: Simple: Password of SALINVOICEUSER

Comment: @vijaya - did you look at the documentation link provided above? That clearly says "Specify the user name and password used to connect to the remote database".